# What is best way to study Python 2.7 with Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, opensocial

I am currently trying to develop Web Sites with Google App Engine with Python 2.7

I would like to use OpenSocial API to develop SNS Games on iPhone / Android platform.

What I need is training material to understand how to deploy GoogleApps Engine with Phthon 2.7

Setting of app.yaml is very hard part.
Today I could able to deploy first Google App Engine with app.yaml file.

```
application: samplexxxxxxx1
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"
```

What is best way to study Python 2.7 syntax in order to develop website with Google App Engine for developing OpenSocial SNS Games?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the "best way". I can share how it worked for me. If you have a decent knowledge with another language, the following resources will help you:

1. [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/) became a canonical resource for ramping up with Python fast and free. I think programming knowledged is assumed. Going through the first chapter of the book you'll pick up a decent Python in few days.
2. Once you have a decent Python (no need to become an expert), go through the ['Getting Started'](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/) of the Google App Engine documentation (the Python 2.7 chapter).
3. I strongly recommend working with a decent python IDE. I now have Eclipse 4.2 with the [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) extension. In addition to many other goodies (Syntax check, completion, jump to reference, etc.), it let you source level debugging and single step, which is great.
4. At this point, gradually expand your knowledge using the Python site documentation, until you are an expert, and able to share your knowledge on SO :-)

Comment: Dear Uri, thank you very much for your answers. I will check [Dive Into Python] web site to learn more about Python. Also I will check python IDE(Eclipse 4.2 with the PyDev).

Comment: I found following [Google I/O 2012 - Getting the Most Out of Python 2.7 on App Engine] Movie on Youtube[link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPHHlnyoGfk)

Answer (score 1):

I recently learnt Python in order to use GAE, and wish that I'd found this style guide earlier in my learning:

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Following this from the beginning will hopefully make things easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

For an easy way to get started, check out the [Getting Started: Python 2.7](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/) tutorial.

For help on using `app.yaml`, check out the [Python Application Configuration](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig) documentation.

Comment: Dear bossylobster, Thank you very much for your information. I will study [app.yaml] setting from these web site.